# Extract from between <br> tags

Tags: html, excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba

I have email addresses in the format below, placed in a column in Excel 2007, like this:

```
<td class="Normal">street name1<br>street name 2<br>city, state zipcode<br>country<br>contact no</TD>
```

Some cells have different `<br>` tags like this:

```
<td class="Normal">street name 1<br>city, state postal<br>country</TD>
```

I can extract the last two  tags using the Excel "text to columns" functions but the transformation is not consistent when extracted in columns and it will take forever to align each column to its right place.

The list all have "," to distinguish the street addresses, and I can use "text-to column' feature to extract all data before "," and then work on the first subset to get the data out, like this:

```
<td class="Normal">street name1<br>street name 2<br>city
```

Is there a way to extract from between the two first `<br>` tags or a script to count the number of `<br>` tags and then use a script to extract each set of `<br>` tags in different columns, as some have one `<br>` tags and other have two `<br>` tags.

Comment: Can you provide a test sample of 2 complete records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim str() As String, tempStr As String
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, colStart As Long, r As Long

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    '-->get last row with data
    For r = 1 To lastRow
        tempStr = Range("A" & r).Value
        colStart = 2
        str = Split(tempStr, "<br>")    '-->split string on tag <br>
        For i = 1 To UBound(str) - 1
            Cells(r, colStart) = str(i)
            colStart = colStart + 1
        Next
    Next r
End Sub
```

See image for reference:
[image]

**EDIT# 1:** Changes based on our discussion
**________________________________________________________________________________**

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim str() As String, tempStr As String
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, colStart As Long, r As Long

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    '-->get last row with data
    For r = 1 To lastRow
        tempStr = Range("A" & r).Value
        colStart = 2
        str = Split(tempStr, "<br>")    '-->split string on tag <br>
        For i = 1 To UBound(str)
            If i = UBound(str) Then
                'this section will take care of the string with just one <br> tag
                If UBound(str) = 1 Then
                    Cells(r, colStart) = str(1)
                End If
            Else
                Cells(r, colStart) = str(i)
                colStart = colStart + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: anyway to extract the Last two words that represent the city. such as:
    ...<br>Santa Monica

Comment: =TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,">",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1))) this worked

Comment: Yes, but its not efficient as it extracts those without <br> tags as well. Any resolution to that ? Maybe an IF statement.

Comment: @HWQ - Can you share the complete line with the tags from which you want to extract Santa Monica.

Comment: this is the complete line with just the first part of the address, after splitting it "226 GOLDEN SPRING DRIVE"

it doesnt have a Br tag but still the formula copies it. 

For <br> tags its working fine.

Comment: @HWQ - From `226 GOLDEN SPRING DRIVE` do you want to extract `SPRING DRIVE`?

Comment: No. I got your script running , i.e extracting between two <br> tags.
Some cells only have one <br> tag in the cell: 
ex: 2234 Drive <br>santa monica

So I just want the last bit after the <br> tag. just "santa monica"

I used the  
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,">",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1))) and it works, but it also extracts the cells with no <br> tags. 

Hope it was clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115600/discussion-between-hwq-and-mrig).